# How can I check whether a remote path is a directory or a file?

Tags: ssh, directory, ls, scp, remote

I am looking for a short an easy way to check whether a remote path points to a directory (or a symlinked directory) or to a readable file.

If it is a directory then I can `scp` multiple specific files from inside that directory to my local system, while if it is a file I can only `scp` that file.

I have the file path given in `scp`-manner as`user@host:/path/to/dir-or-file`.

Note: On the local system (MobaXterm on Windows) I have `bash`, `scp` and `ssh` available, while the remote system (on which the path sits I want to check on) is a full Linux distro.

Comment: Is your aim to be able to _transfer_ the file or directory, or is it to get a string saying whether it's a file or a directory, or an exit status that you can later use to decide what to do with?

Comment: @Kusalananda Well, I want to now whether it is a file or directory, becauseif it is a directory then I can `scp` multiple specific files from *inside* that directory to my local system, while if it is a file I can only `scp` that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking to transfer the file (if it's a file), or parts of the directory (if it's a directory).

```
if ! scp user@host:/path/to/dir-or-file local/path
then
    scp user@host:/path/to/dir-or-file/some-specific-file local/path
fi
```

If `scp` is told to transfer a directory without its `-r` option, it will fail.  You may use this to detect whether the given path on the remote host is a directory or not, and then invoke `scp` a second time to get specific files inside the directory if the first `scp` couldn't get the pathname as a file.

Of course, if you want to transfer the *whole* directory (if it's a directory) you could just do

```
scp -r user@host:/path/to/dir-or-file local/path
```

which would work regardless of whether the path is for a directory or file.

Comment: That's the easiest for me to use. Great!

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following command:

```
ssh user@host file /path/to/dir-or-file
```

The result will be among possible file types:

```
/path/to/dir-or-file: directory
/path/to/dir-or-file: symbolic link to `whatever'
/path/to/dir-or-file: UTF-8 Unicode text
/path/to/dir-or-file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable ... 
....
```

*Note:* if you only need to test for directory or not inside a bash shell script, you could merely use test like:

```
ssh user@host test -d /path/to/dir-or-file
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
  echo this is a dir
else 
  echo this is not a dir
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty approach, if you don't mind an error message and you only need to copy non-dot files, is this

```
scp -p asuser@host:'/path/to/dir-or-file/*' asuser@host:'/path/to/dir-or-file' .
```

The trailing dot copies the remote files to the current directory. Adjust to taste. The `-p` flag retains the time stamp and permissions. Omit if those aren't required.

Answer (score -1):

This info is also available in output of ls:
the first symbol in first column is:
"d" for directory
"l" for links

Comment: But `ls` gives me the directory of my *local* system.

Comment: Plus the “d” or “l” indicator you get only when specifying the `-l` option.